# Names of employees working in the department where the employee receives the high salary

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, and I'm trying to get names of employees working in the department where the employee receives the highest salary.

I succeeded to return the employee with the highest salary, but now I want to perform union with their `Dno` and the rest of the employee's row, how I can do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fname, Lname, salary
FROM employee 
WHERE Dno = (SELECT Dno FROM employee WHERE MAX(salary));

/*names of employees working in the department where the employee receives the high salary
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close, but you should be checking the *salary* in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, salary
FROM employee 
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee);
```

We could also use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` here, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname, salary, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) rnk
    FROM employee
)

SELECT Fname, Lname, salary
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a list of all of the employees in the same department as the one with the highest salary, you wouldn't need to perform an additional union, as you could just use an [`ORDER BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on salary and select the department for that highest salary level in a [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause as seen below:

```
SELECT  Fname,
        Lname,
        salary
FROM    employee
WHERE   Dno = (SELECT TOP 1 Dno FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC)
```

Comment: when i use DECLARE its given me error, and the second solution not working, its give me only the highest paid employee without his friend in same department.

Comment: I've adjusted my response as it was initially unclear what you were looking for. In your case, you can just get the highest paid department via an `ORDER BY` clause in your subquery and use that to select your users as seen in the updated response.

Answer (score 0):

You can have nested select like this :

```
Select * from employee where deoptno in 
   ( Select deptno from empoloyee where salary = (Select max(salary) from employee))
```

Comment: when i write this, its give me only the employee that revive highest salary.
and i want something else,
i want all employee that working with same dno with employee that receive highest salary.